# How to pass all values from multiple Secrets to env variables in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I have multiple Secrets in a Kubernetes. All of them contain many values, as example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: paypal-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID: base64_PP_client_id
  PAYPAL_SECRET: base64_pp_secret
stringData:
  PAYPAL_API: https://api.paypal.com/v1
  PAYPAL_HOST: api.paypal.com
```

I'm curious how to pass all of the values from all `Secrets` to a `ReplicaSet` for example.

I tried this one approach:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: pp-debts
  labels:
    environment: prod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      environment: prod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        environment: prod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: integration-app
        image: my-container-image
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
          name: intercom-secret
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: paypal-secret
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: postgres-secret
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: redis-secret
```

But when I connected to the pod, and looked on the env variables, I was able to see only values from the `redis-secret`.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try using one `envFrom` with multiple entries under it as below:

```
      - name: integration-app
        image: my-container-image
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: intercom-secret
        - secretRef:
            name: paypal-secret
        - secretRef:
            name: postgres-secret
        - secretRef:
            name: redis-secret
```

There's an example at the bottom of [this blog post by David Chua](https://web.archive.org/web/20211122093817/https://dchua.com/posts/2017-04-21-load-env-variables-from-configmaps-and-secrets-upon-pod-boot/)

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I'll try this advice in 90 minutes, after lunch :D

Comment: I received back error: 
error validating data: [ValidationError(ReplicaSet.spec.template.spec.containers[0].envFrom[0]): unknown field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvFromSource, ValidationError(ReplicaSet.spec.template.spec.containers[0].envFrom[1]): unknown field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvFromSource, ValidationError(ReplicaSet.spec.template.spec.containers[0].envFrom[2]): unknown field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvFromSource, ValidationError(ReplicaSet.spec.template.spec.containers[0].envFrom[3]): unknown field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.EnvFromSource];

Comment: I edited the above yaml to make it work right; the original post had wrong formatting which caused @AlexFruzenshtein's error in comment above.